# Где создать свою 3D карту чтобы строить на ней маршруты и встроить ее на сайт?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, 3d

Попробовал Яндекс.Карты - очень хорошая штука, встроил ее на сайт, сделал генерацию маршрутов, расставление меток на нужном участке карты и тд. В яндекс картах можно использовать свою картинку (2D - JPEG) вместо карты, и на ней уже создавать маршруты и точки, но мне нужно не картинку, а свою 3D модель (карту в 3D со своими 3D зданиями и тд), и на ней уже расставить свои метки, маршруты и тд, чтобы потом ее встроить на сайт.
wrld3d.com подошла бы, если бы можно было создавать (или загружать) свои модели зданий (уже готовые там просто убогие)

Есть идея просто сделать весь функционал карты с помощью three.js, но не хотелось бы изобретать велосипед

Comment: Cesium? Mapboxgl-js?

Answer (score 0):

Яндекс.карты на самом деле дерьмо, нормальные это лефлет либо map box. Просто набираешь leaflet 3d tiles например и ищешь решения, которые тебе подойдут.
Вот полностью готовое: https://osmbuildings.org/?lat=55.75045&lon=37.61749&zoom=16.0&tilt=30 но серверную часть они не распространяют, если у тебя свои модели, то если только спарсить их тайлы(там кастомные геоджсон) и подправить.